# How to overcome OutOfMemoryException pulling large xml documents from an API?

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

I am pulling 1M+ records from an API. The pull works ok, but I'm getting an out of memory exception when attempting to `ReadToEnd` into a string variable.

Here's the code:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();

        HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        client.Timeout = 2100000;//35 minutes
        WebResponse apiResponse = client.GetResponse();

        Stream receivedStream = apiResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receivedStream);

        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at MyApplication.DataBuilder.getDataFromAPICall(String uri) in
    c:\Users\RDESLONDE\Documents\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication\DataBuilder.cs:line 578
at MyApplication.DataBuilder.GetDataFromAPIAsXDoc(String uri) in
c:\Users\RDESLONDE\Documents\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication\DataBuilder.cs:line 543
```

What can I do to work around this?

Comment: You should show the relevant code.

Comment: Try looping `reader.ReadLine() + WritetoFile` instead of `reader.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: L.B. can I read that into a string and process into an XDocument...or do I have to break up into smaller XDocuments?

Comment: You may have to use `XmlReader` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Comment: Peacemaker, the problem is the API returns XML with characters that I have to encode (ex: &) and so I have to put it into a string first for encoding those characters.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde Then you'll need to do something to break it up into chunks.  Ideally you'd perform multiple queries to the API and have the results returned in pages, rather than all at once, and then process those results in batches.  If that's not possible, then while reading the data line by line (i.e. not using `ReadToEnd`) you'll need to find appropriate places to pause, process what you have so far, and then continue on.

Comment: Aren't there any parameters in the API methods through which you could divide your data retrieval over a series of smaller responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) is the way to go when memory is an issue. It is also fastest.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your file is too big for your environment. Loading the DOM for a large file can be problematic, especially when using the win32 platform (you haven't indicated whether this is the case).

You can combine the speed and memory efficiency of XmlReader with the convenience of XElement/Xnode, etc and use an XStreamingElement to save the transformed content after processing. This is much more memory-efficient for large files

Here's an example in pseudo-code:

```
    // use a XStreamingElement for writing
    var st = new XStreamingElement("root"); 
    using(var xr = new XmlTextReader(stream))
    {
        while (xr.Read())
        {
            // whatever you're interested in
            if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
            {
                var node = XNode.ReadFrom(xr) as XElement;
                if (node != null)
                {
                    ProcessNode(node);
                    st.Add(node);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    st.Save(outstream); // or st.WriteTo(xmlwriter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you didn't show your code but it sounds like the entire file is being loaded into memory. That's what you need to avoid.

Best if you can use a stream to process the file without loading the entire thing in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyXmlDocument : IDisposable
    {

        private bool _disposed = false;
        private XmlDocument _xmldoc;

        public XmlDocument xmldoc
        {
            get { return _xmldoc; }
            

        }
        public MyXmlDocument()
        {

            _xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        }

        ~MyXmlDocument()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

        // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        
        }

        // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                this._xmldoc = null;
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            _disposed = true;
        }

    }
```

You can use this and then you can write the code like

```
Using(MyXmlDocument doc = new MyXmlDocument())
{
  doc.xmldoc = xmldoc.Load(new StreamReader(file));
  
}
```