# C# Large Complex Object Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

i really don't now what to do anymore, i searched the whole internet and tried so many things but i can not deserialize my object to a class.

At first i will give you my data structure:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Plugin")]
public class SiXmlPlugin
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Version")]
    public long Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("VersionString")]
    public String VersionString { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Files")]
    public List<SiFile> Files = new List<SiFile>();

    [XmlElement("Folders")]
    public List<SiFolder> Folders = new List<SiFolder>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Folder")]
public class SiFolder
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Files")]
    public List<SiFile> Files = new List<SiFile>();

    [XmlElement("Folders")]
    public List<SiFolder> Folders = new List<SiFolder>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("File")]
public class SiFile
{
    [XmlAttribute("Filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

These are my 3 classes.
I am trying to deserialize an object of SiXmlPlugin.
As you see the structure is quite complex.
The serialized file has got a size of 480 mb, so it is quite large!

Serialization of the object works fine.
But when i deserialize it i always get an OutOfMemoryException.
I tried Xml-, Binaryserializer and also protobuf-net but with all of them i get the same exception.

I know that the structure is not so good, but in this case it is needed.
Anyway does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?
I am really stuck with this situation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you allowed to exchange some data structures to get more memory efficient data structures?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710337/how-to-overcome-outofmemoryexception-pulling-large-xml-documents-from-an-api

Comment: Can you add the code for (de)serialization?  Is it using XmlSerializer?

Comment: Which target platform do you use? You may switch to X64/AnyCPU to be able to use more memory in case you are now compiling for X86... Another option may be not to initialize the Files and Folders property in the constructor.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the data once you have it all deserialized? Knowing how you're using the data could enable us to offer more alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If file is too big to fit into memory, try processing it as you read it and not loading completely at once. You can achieve it with `XmlReader`. [Here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader) you can find an example how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

See if following code works.  Haven't got a chance to fully test code, but it seems to work.  I generated my own xml and not sure if it is exactly the same as yours.  I also didn't add the contents property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        const string READFILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //new Write(FOLDER, READFILENAME);
            new SiXmlPlugin(READFILENAME);
        }


    }

    //[XmlRoot("Plugin")]
    public class SiXmlPlugin
    {
        public static SiXmlPlugin root = null;
        //[XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[XmlAttribute("Version")]
        public long Version { get; set; }

        //[XmlAttribute("VersionString")]
        public String VersionString { get; set; }

        //[XmlElement("Files")]
        public List<SiFile> Files = new List<SiFile>();

        //[XmlElement("Folders")]
        public List<SiFolder> Folders = new List<SiFolder>();

        public SiXmlPlugin() { }
        public SiXmlPlugin(string filename)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Plugin");
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            root = new SiXmlPlugin();
            int depth = reader.Depth;
            ReadFolderRecursive(root.Folders, reader, depth);

        }
        public static void ReadFolderRecursive(List<SiFolder> folders, XmlReader reader, int depth)
        {
            SiFolder newFolder = null;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                XmlNodeType nodeType = reader.NodeType;
                switch (nodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                        reader.Read();
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {
                            case "Files":
                                reader.ReadStartElement();
                                ReadFolderRecursive(folders, reader, reader.Depth); 
                                break;
                            case "File":
                                SiFile newFile = new SiFile();
                                folders.Last().Files.Add(newFile);
                                newFile.Filename = reader.GetAttribute("Name");
                                reader.ReadStartElement();

                                break;
                            case "Folders":
                                int newDepth = reader.Depth;
                                if (newDepth < depth) return;

                                if (newDepth == depth)
                                {
                                    newFolder = new SiFolder();
                                    newFolder.Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name");
                                    folders.Add(newFolder);
                                    reader.ReadStartElement();
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                   if (newFolder.Folders == null)
                                    {
                                        newFolder.Folders = new List<SiFolder>();
                                   }
                                   ReadFolderRecursive(newFolder.Folders, reader, newDepth);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                reader.ReadStartElement();
                                break;
                        }

                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Attribute:

                        break;
                    default:
                        reader.Read();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


    //[XmlRoot("Folder")]
    public class SiFolder
    {
        //[XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[XmlElement("Files")]
        public List<SiFile> Files = new List<SiFile>();

        //[XmlElement("Folders")]
        public List<SiFolder> Folders = new List<SiFolder>();

        }
    }

    //[XmlRoot("File")]
    public class SiFile
    {
        //[XmlAttribute("Filename")]
        public string Filename { get; set; }

        //[XmlElement("Content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }


    public class Write
    {
        static XmlWriter writer = null;

        public Write(string folderName,string readFilename)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(readFilename, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            writer.WriteStartElement("Plugin");

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folders");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("NumberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("NumberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Files");
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }

}
```